# radius of convergence and exact interval of convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$$\sum _n (-1)^n \frac {x^{2n+1}} {(2n+1)!}$$
I have solved this problem: the radius of convergence is coming to be infinity and hence the interval of convergence is $\Bbb R$. But in the answer it is given that the radius of convergence is $1$ and the interval of exact convergence is $[-1,1]$.

Comment: YOU are right :-) D'Alembert rule for example... This is the development for $\sin x$.

Comment: But is my answer  right ?I used d Alembert's rule here.

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: Seems like somebody overlooked the $!$. The series $$\sum_n (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2n+1}$$ has radius of convergence $1$ and converges on $[-1,1]$.